# Que significa atribuir Math.random() > 0.5 a uma variável?

Tags: java, random

O que significa isso `Math.random() > 0.5;` em um `boolean`?
Aqui tem exemplo:

```
class Pro {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numero = 10;
        boolean[] array = new boolean[numero];
        for(int i= 0; i< array.length; i++) {
           array[i] = Math.random() > 0.5;
           System.out.print(array[i] + "\t");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O `Math.random()` irá gerar um valor entre 0 e 0.999999 (tende ao limite de 1, mas não atinge o 1).

Logo o seu trecho de código:

```
array[i] = Math.random() > 0.5;
```

Está verificando se o valor gerado pela função `random` é maior que 0.5

Se for maior, é setado `true` para aquela posição do array. Do contrário, seta como `false`.

Comment: No caso seria se o valor do array percorrido no for seja menor que 0.5 ?

Comment: Não é o valor do array, e sim o valor da comparação entre um número aleatório e o 0.5

Comment: O valor gerado no random?

Comment: Isso. Você tem um array que armazena valores boleanos, certo? Cada iteração dentro do for irá se encarregar de verificar se o número que fora gerado de forma aleatória é menor ou maior que 0.5. Dependendo do valor que se obtenha, o valor daquela posição (no caso, a posição será determinada pelo inteiro `i`) será `true` ou `false`.

Answer (score 6):

A intenção do autor do código é que cada elemento do vetor tenha 50% de chance de ser `true` e 50% de chance de ser `false`.

Na prática, isso não vai ser *totalmente* verdade por questões matemáticas, mas é próximo o suficiente.

Quanto ao código, `Math.random() > 0.5` é uma **expressão** que retorna um valor **booleano**, isto é, verdadeiro ou falso.

Como acontece com qualquer expressão matemática, você pode atribuir o resultado a uma variável do mesmo tipo gerado pela expressão.

Por exemplo, o trecho:

```
boolean var = Math.random() > 0.5;
```

É a forma "resumida" de:

```
boolean var;
if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    var = true;
} else {
    var = false;
}
```

Comment: Sem querer criticar, afinal de contas você é usuário participativo e um excelente moderador, mas aonde isto responde ao que o autor perguntou? Soa mais como um comentário. - Fica bravo comigo não :(

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Do meu ponto de vista, esta é a única resposta que responde à pergunta: o que significa atribuir .... a uma variável? Veja a resposta aceita diz o que o código faz, mas não diz o que isso significa. Eu imagino um monte de gente lendo a resposta é ficando sem entender porque macacos alguém vai comparar um número aleatório com `0.5`.

Comment: Eu pensei que o autor não tive-se entendido o `>`, ou melhor dizendo o que são "ifs inline" (não sei se este é o nome mais adequado), resumindo, o que eu entendi é que ele quer entender é o conjunto todo e o que responderia seria explicar os operadores... Se bem que isso deveria ser o principio basico para se inicar na programação, então acabo ficando confuso se é algo que vale levar adiante. Todavia vou considerar que o autor responda se é isso mesmo, pois parece que só ele pode afirmar. ;) Obrigado

Comment: Num vai negativar, hein? Senão eu abro um post no meta é digo que todo mundo nesse site é chato. :P

Comment: Admito que passou pela minha cabeça hehehe :) ... mas o problema é o problema mesmo é a pergunta e não as respostas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Brincadeiras à parte, acho que faz sentido sua preocupação. Muita gente tem dificuldade também com expressões que não são colocas num `IF`, por exemplo.  Melhorei a resposta colocando uma explicação de como funciona a expressão.

Comment: Achei que ficou muito boa a explicação e estes exemplos eram o que faltavam (se entendi a duvida do autor) +1

Answer (score 5):

Significa exatamente um booleano. Qual é a resposta da expressão `Math.random() > 0.5`? Será `true` ou `false`, certo? Ela verificará se o número sorteado é maior que meio e obter o resultado se é verdadeiro ou falso, então a resposta será guardada na variável apropriada.